# Generating minimal unsat core using Z3 Python API

Tags: z3, z3py

Z3 supports minimal unsat core detection with the following option.

```
(set-option :smt.core.minimize true)
```

as documented [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1761#issuecomment-405871718).

In the API documentation, only the simple use of tracking unsat cores is mentioned. Is there a way to achieve **minimal** unsat core detection with the Z3 the Python API.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `assert_and_track` function for this purpose. See https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/python/z3/z3.py#L6571-L6599 which has an example right in the documentation. To tell z3 to minimize the cores, use:

```py
s.set(':core.minimize', True)
```

Note that the notion of a "minimal" unsat core doesn't really exist; as you can have two different sets with the same cardinality both of which can act as the unsat-core. And as far as I know z3 makes no guarantees about "minimality" other than "best-effort."

Also relevant: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/888 where tactics and unsat-core minimization don't quite play nicely with other.